# Calculation of critical values

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-test, z-test, two-sample

Are the critical values for the two-sample t-test with unequal variances calculated the same as for the two-sample z-test?

Answer (score 0):

The critical values of t-test is calculated from the [t table](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3672.htm) with the associated degree of freedom; while however the critical value of a z-test is calculated from the [z-table](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3671.htm). If the degree of freedom in Student-t is large, you'll obtain a value very similar to the one obtained from the z-table, but they're not the same (or close) in general.